# How to access Main Rails App controllers variable inside the Rails Engine application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-engines

I have created a new Rails engine "ProductSearch" and now I have a condition here that I need a controller variable that from Main_app Controller so I am unable to get this variable while executing the action from my Engine APP.

Answer (score 0):

Prepend with `::` like this: `::MainAppController`. The `::` says, essentially, 'look for the constant (the controller) in the global namespace' (which the MainApp that includes your engine).